# Order of albums with ALAssetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using ALAssetsLibrary to get the photo albums. Is there any way to replicate the exact order the albums appear in, as presented in Photos app? Currently my code always returns the albums in the same order, regardless of how I arrange them in Photos. Here's the code.

```
    groups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
        usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
        {
            if (group == NULL) // last
                return;

            [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
            [groups addObject:group];
        }
        failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
        {
            [Utils alertError:@"Albums not available"];
        }];
```

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: I didn't found an aswer and assumed that Photos keeps an internal index, not shared with ALAssets.